# How to collect atributes of a function or array function in javascript legacy mode?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if I didn't express myself well in the title, but I believe that through the explanation/example of to understand better.

If I need to pass attributes in a function, I can group these values in an array and later use this array with Operator Spread.

But, these values ​​are stored in any attribute of the object itself?

```js
var classic_mode_example = (...x) => x.reduce((cache,value) => cache + value);

console.log(classic_mode_example(1,2,3,5));   //return: 11

var legacy_mode_idea = () => (this.atributes).reduce((cache,value) => cache + value);

console.log(legacy_mode_idea(1,2,3,5));   //return: Error. It's not exists?
```

Comment: What is `this.atributes` supposed to be?

Comment: any value that the function receives but that has not been defined in the structure.

Comment: don't use arrow function if you need legacy mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```js
var legacy_mode_idea = function() {
    return (Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)).reduce((cache,value) => cache + value);
}

console.log(legacy_mode_idea(1,2,3,5));
```

Comment: thanks, is it =) In arrow functions something like that doesn't exist right?